# Jest finds tests but doesn't collect coverage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, istanbul

I trying to collect test coverage for [this project](https://github.com/lualparedes/lualparedes.github.io) using

```sh
yarn test --coverage # i.e. "react-scripts test --coverage"
```

My jest config is this:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.ts*"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    }
  }
```

and my folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public/
├── README.md
├── src/
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.test.tsx
│   ├── App.tsx
│   ├── assets/
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── Emoji/
│   │   │   ├── Emoji.test.tsx
│   │   │   ├── Emoji.tsx
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   └── Home/
│   │       ├── Home.css
│   │       ├── Home.test.tsx
│   │       ├── Home.tsx
│   │       └── index.ts
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
│   └── serviceWorker.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── yarn-error.log
└── yarn.lock
```

Jest is being able to find all the tests but it fails to collect coverage:

```
 PASS  src/components/Home/Home.test.tsx
 PASS  src/components/Emoji/Emoji.test.tsx
 PASS  src/App.test.tsx
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.432s
Ran all test suites.
```

What am I missing? What should I add to the configuration to get the coverage?

**Any hint is welcome :)**

### Tries

1. Changing the glob pattern to `"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"`.
2. Removing `node_modules` and then running `yarn` to reinstall everything.
3. Removing `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, and then reinstall everything, which led to [another bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVsYo.png), which I tried to solve installing that particular dependency, but it didn't work.
4. Cloning the repository from GitHub and then running the command on the fresh version.
5. Switching to a different Node version (v10.16.2, and v11.7.0).

Comment: I downloaded your project and ran the test. It collected coverage correctly

Comment: @TienDuong O.O, then it must be something related to my environment, what's your OS and Node version? did you run the tests using yarn or npm?

Comment: I used Win 10, Node 10.16 and yarn

Comment: @TienDuong thanks for the info, I downgraded my Node version and rerun and still no luck. I'm using Linux though, but I'm also able to collect coverage in a work project that has almost the exact config in this machine, so it's kinda weird :/

Comment: I had similar trouble, not sure if for similar reasons. I added "--watchAll", so `react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll` and it worked...

Comment: @atomictom it worked! thanks! please post the comment as an answer to accept it as the solution :)

Comment: adding --watchAll or --watchAll:false does not work for me

Comment: the glob patterns in `collectCoverageFrom` and `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` are often cause for trouble. It's a good idea to comment them out and see if it works then.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The quick fix I said in my comment, using `--watchAll` instead, eg: `react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll`.

Just for future reference, I think ideally we should be using `--watch`, which would only run on changed files, but it gave me the same trouble. I think it's related to this issue  ['--coverage --watch' should calculate coverage for all files at first iteration](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8992) and also this issue [No coverage when running in watch mode](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7331). I'm not sure why it worked for some people and not you, presumably something to do with Git and staging of files.

Comment: yes, my problem('Failed to collect coverage from untested files') has been fixed just by using:     
     --coverage --watchAll

Comment: Wow the linked `--coverage --watch` issue explains a lot. Why would they only collect coverage from changed files in git by default?!

Answer (score 27):

Not necessarily the solution in the original questioner's case, but i ran into the exact same problem and this was my solution:

I found that when upgrading jest (from 23 to 26) that i had this issue, and the resolution was to run with the `--no-cache` option. Presumably they changed something about these coverage reports internally such that the cached data was incompatible.

Comment: I have upgraded from 24 to 26 and running with `--no-cache` once solved the issue. After that I had to use `--watchAll` for the coverage task, otherwise it was showing empty results

Comment: @AntonMatosov could u please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727591/jest-coverage-in-a-node-typescript-project-always-returns-empty/64745848#64745848, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: In my case, the jest coverage is updating, but the Istanbul coverage html file is not.

Answer (score 15):

Seems to be working fine on Linux Mint 19.2. I'd suggest changing your jest config to something a bit more flexible:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    }
  }
```

And then change your `package.json` test script if you're using `npm` (with `yarn` you can just append `--coverage`, for example: `yarn test --coverage`; however, with `npm`, it'll just ignore it). So I'd suggest either doing this:

```
 "test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
```

Or, I'd recommend using `yarn` over `npm`. To install yarn, use one of the following [methods](https://tecadmin.net/install-yarn-debian/).

Working:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I changed the glob pattern, I'm using yarn, and I'm also using Linux Mint (19.1), but for some obscure reason Jest still doesn't collect the coverage: https://i.imgur.com/06ZXQNA.png.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't replicate it. So... my guess is it might be your related to your node_modules folder. Try deleting the node_modules folder and the yarn.lock file. Then reinstall your deps. Or, better yet, clone your repo into another folder, install the deps and try again. This can at least narrow it down to be project-related or OS-related.

Comment: I tried deleting node_modules and then reinstalling and it didn't work. I also tried deleting yarn.lock too, but then I got this error: https://i.imgur.com/qfBEt4S.png, which I tried to solve by reinstalling that particular dependency but it didn't work either. My guess is that it has something to do with some mismatching version of one of the many random dependencies, but both the initial issue and this new one seem to be rabbit holes :/

Comment: Have you tried cloning your repo into a new folder? If not, please do so: 1. Open a terminal on your desktop (or open a terminal and `cd ~/Desktop`), 2. type `git clone git@github.com:lualparedes/lualparedes.github.io.git`, 2.  `cd lualparedes.github.io`, 4. `yarn install` and 5. `yarn test --coverage`. If that fails, then I'd recommend uninstalling node and npm completely and then reinstalling it again.

Comment: I tried cloning the repo, and it didn't work. I also tried switching Node versions but it didn't work either, I've tried with v11.7.0 (default version on my computer at the moment) and 10.16 (version used by @Tien Duong), but still no luck.

Comment: No idea then. Since it's seems related to your system, I'd recommend the following: 1. Make sure you have enough available RAM (ideally 16GB), 2. Install Linux Mint 19.2 (or reinstall 19.1) and try again. 3. Create a bug report here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues and include everything above (system specs, include the repo, and what you've tried to remedy the issue, .etc).

Comment: I only have 8GB, but I'm able to collect coverage from a huge work project (200+ test files) in the same machine, and that project has almost the exact same configuration —I literally copied chunks of the config files of that project. 

I'll probably use this as an opportunity to learn a little bit about Jest internals, but turning the website into a blog is higher in my priority list at the moment. Thanks so much for taking the time to think about the issue and even follow up for several days! :)

Comment: Why does the src folder appear that low number? I mean shouldn't it be higher? @MattCarlotta

Answer (score 11):

What helped me is that instead of

```
npm run test
```

or

```
npm run test --watchall
```

I did this:

```
npm run test a
```

and

```
npm run test a -- --coverage
```

Comment: For whatever reason, that actually shows the files for me. But only works by filtering the tests being run. So it's only a hint at what might be the real solution here.

Answer (score 5):

For me, `<rootDir>` was missing, it worked fine after adding it.

`"collectCoverageFrom": [ "<rootDir>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}" ]`

Comment: Thanks Nagraje, that was the solution for me!

Answer (score 4):

Been there...
You're missing one more parameter in Jest config:

```
collectCoverage: true
```

Answer (score 4):

In our case the problem was with the jest `rootDir` setting (in our package.json) which we had set to `tests`. Jest therefore ignored our `src/` folder where our actual source code was. The rolution was to tell jest about both folders:

### package.json old

```
"jest": {
  "rootDir: "tests"
}
```

### package.json new

```
"jest": {
  "roots": [
    "src",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems the problem is with the flag --watchAll
Without setting it to false it does not generate coverage

```
react-scripts test --reporters=jest-junit --reporters=default --coverage --coverageDirectory='testresults/coverage' --coverageReporters=cobertura --coverageReporters=lcov --watchAll=false
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I've changed the folder's name and forgot to update the `collectCoverageFrom` key under the `jest.config.ts` file.

Answer (score 1):

1º - Try removing your jest.config file.js (if it exists).

2º - Keep the default Jest settings only in your package.json file, so you don't get confused when compiler both settings.

like this:

```js
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|
      @expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|
      @react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|
      unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
      "!**/*/*.d.ts",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/babel.config.js",
      "!**/jest.setup.js"
    ]
}
```

3º - With these settings made, in package.json file, separate the scripts to run the Jest. One for testing and one for collecting Coverage

like this:

```js
"scripts": {
   ...,
   "test": "jest --watch --coverage=false",
   "testWithCoverage": "jest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was testing React Native/Expo app with the option `cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache'`. Deleting the `.jest` directory has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to get to work by deleting cache and do `npm install`. In windows cache location (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours and these are the solution I found recently.
In **package.json** I have to set the ***collectCoverageFrom*** and ***coverageReporters*** to:

```
{   "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
        "cobertura",
        "lcov",
        "text"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
        "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

And since I'm using npm:

```
npm test --coverage
```

Btw, I'm using **Vite**—just in case you're curious.

Comment: **Multiple configurations found:** -> `Implicit config resolution does not allow multiple configuration files.
  Either remove unused config files or select one explicitly with `--config`.`

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js too, adding **collectCoverageFrom** in **package.json** helped me to find the uncovered files.

My package.json,

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "api-testing"],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "api-testing"],
    "collectCoverageFrom": ["**/controllers/*.js"]
  }
}
```

Before adding **collectCoverageFrom**

[image: Before adding collectCoverageFrom]

After adding **collectCoverageFrom**

[image: After adding collectCoverageFrom]

Basically, without adding **collectCoverageFrom**, it only includes the files that has test cases (i.e. the **.test.js** files in the usual naming convent) .

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the `"src/**/*.ts*"` wildcard pattern you're using to cover `.ts` and `.tsx` files might be the problem.  I would try this pattern to include both file types:

```js
collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}']
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the coverage stopped showing just at a random rerun of `npm test`. What helped me was to change `packages.json`

from

```
"test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
```

to

```
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

run `npm test`

then change back to

```
"test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
```

run `npm test` again -> coverage shown

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your package.json

```
"jest": {
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/path/to/ignore/"
    ]
  }
```

**This will solve the issue of yours instead of specifying a lot of these commands**